# Angular 4 navigation hooks

Tags: angular

Let's say I have two components with their corresponding URLs being:

1. /home
2. /login

Now I'm hoping when the browser navigates to `/home`, something like `onEnterHome` could be called, and when the browser navigates from `/home` to `/login`, `onLeaveHome`, and `onEnterLogin` could be called. I googled and found some documentations talking about component lifecycle hooks. But that does not seem to be exactly what I was looking for. So is there any event hooks to track url/component navigation? Thanks.

Comment: You can setup Routes and use CanActivate / CanDeactivate route guards

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. You can subscribe to [Angular Router events](https://angular.io/api/router/Event) for that. Each event has an `id` and the `url`, .e.g `NavigationStart` and `NavigationEnd`.